# Web Config Error Causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this inside my Web.config:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings> 
        <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="admin@xxxxxx.com"> 
            <network defaultCredentials="false" host="mail.xxxxxx.com" password="xxxxxxx" port="25" userName="admin@xxxxxx.com" enableSsl="false" /> 
        </smtp> 
    </mailSettings> 
</system.net>
```

This causes any request to my website becomes

> 500 Internal Server Error

This makes the hosting server assumes that my Web.config is not valid. Before it was fine, my Web site can run with no problem. I cannot see any syntax error in it?

What is going on here?

Comment: Can you provide error details? Use browser's network tab to see what error you get.

Comment: Have you checked your server logs? It's an internal server error which often (typically) means you've got an exception somewhere which has not been handled.

Comment: Make sure you XML encode any values (like passwords) that may contain characters that can't appear in regular XML (like & => &amp;)

Comment: @GeoffCox Yes this was the problem. I have "&" in my email password. Using "&amp" does not work. I just need to change the password. If you post the answer here, I will mark your answer and vote it for your reputation. Thank you

Comment: You can see in XML predefined characters: https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-entity-names/predefined.html. Ensure that five predefined chars are escaped properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting from comment thread as answer: You likely have a special character in your password that may require XML encoding.